# How to use passport.js with neo4j

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j, passport.js

I am trying to implement passport.js in my express app with node js and using neo4j as the database.

I my application, there are no models defined for neo4j (unlike mongo db, I couldn't find a reference to define models for the neo4j database in Node.js). For example, if I was using mongodb I would have a user model and then use User.findOne for the following passport.js authentication code:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

This other example is from my actual code with mongodb as the database:

```
// Load user model
const User = mongoose.model('users');

module.exports = function(passport){
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, (email, password, done) => {
        // Match user
        User.findOne({
            email: email
        }).then(user => {
            if(!user){
                return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
            }
            // Match password
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if(err) throw err;

                if(isMatch){
                    return done(null, user);
                }else{
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Password incorrect'});
                }
            })
        })
    }));
```

my question is, how would I use this with neo4j as my database.

Comment: **https://github.com/mfong/node-neo4j-passport-template**

Comment: Thanks @NightProgrammer , already going through that example but it seems a bit outdated.

Comment: Have you already found a solution? I'm facing the same problem at the moment, but just started to dug into it

Comment: No, I haven found a solution yet so stopped working on it for a while.